# convert QByteArray to QString is empty

Tags: qt

I use QTcpSocket::readAll() got a QByteArray. However when I used QString::fromUtf8() to convert it to QString, I got a empty QString.

```
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream in(&ba,QIODevice::ReadWrite);
in << socket->readAll();
QByteArray request = ba;
qDebug() <<"ba:" << ba; // right message
```

Then:

```
QString request = QString::fromUtf8(ba); // request is empty
QString request = QString(ba) //also empty
```

Comment: what is the output of  `qDebug() <<"ba:" << ba;`?

Comment: What is `QByteArray request = ba;` for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your bytearray has different text encoding (cyrillic - win1251 or DOS - cp866). For converting bytearray with specific encoding into string use [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html)

```
QByteArray ba("abcd");
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251");
QString str = codec->toUnicode(ba);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your message is not coded in utf8, maybe GB18030.
In your main function, you must set your codec.

```
QTextCodec *gb = QTextCodec::codecForName("gb18030");
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(gb);
```

Then you can process the message(I am using Qt4).

```
QByteArray ba = s->readAll();
QString request = QString::fromLocal8Bit(ba.data(),ba.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
QJsonDocument doc(jobject);
ByteArray arr = doc.toJson();

//Just cast
QString result = static_cast<QString>(doc.toJson());
```